# PHP PDO - Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I am trying to run a query using database credentials from a config file but I keep getting the following error: `Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null`

config.php file:

```
$host = 'xxxx';
$dbname = 'xxxx';
$username = 'xxxx';
$password = 'xxxx.';   

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host; dbname=$dbname;", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "$e->getMessage()";
}
```

functions.php

```
session_start();
include 'config.php';

    function getAddress(){
       $output = "";
       if (isset($_SESSION['userid'])){
            $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
            try {
                $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT address FROM users WHERE id = :userid');
                $stmt->bindParam(':userid', $userid);
                $stmt->execute();
                $result = $stmt -> fetch();
                if(empty($result)){
                    $output = "Your information cannot be retrieved";
                } else {
                    $output = $result['address'];
                }       
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                $output = $e->getMessage();
            }
            $conn = null;
            } else {
            $output = "An error has occured, please try again";
            }
        return $output;
    }
```

index.php (html page)

```
<?php 
session_start();
include 'functions.php';
?>
...
<p><?php echo getAddress();?></p>
...
```

So my index page runs a function (`getAddress()`) from the functions.php script which connects to a db using credentials stored in config.php.

Comment: You have to pass the connection to the function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call to a member function prepare() on null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35959311/call-to-a-member-function-prepare-on-null)

Comment: @JayBlanchard how would you suggest I do this?

Comment: `echo getAddress($conn);` and change the function call to `function getAddress($conn)`

Comment: Could just declare the $conn as global in the function.  Better to pass as a parameter as already suggested though - IMHO.

Comment: @JayBlanchard it works! Thanks. Just for educational purposes, why do I need to pass $conn to the function when the function has access to the $conn variable in the config.php file?

Comment: It *doesn't* have access, that's the point. `$conn` in the scope of the function has no access to `$conn` outside of the function. In this case `$conn` inside the function is only a convenient name for what we passed into the function.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Blimey you're right, those programming lessons from years ago are coming back to me. Would there be a better way to acheive this, or is passing the variable through the function sufficient?

Comment: @JayBlanchard By the way, feel free to submit your suggestion as an answer so that not only can I mark it as the best answer, but others can see it more clearly.

Comment: Done @Matt9Atkins - glad I could help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the scope of the function call you need to pass in the connection to the function. First, setup the function call to receive the connection:

```
function getAddress($conn)
```

`$conn` here is just a convenient name for the variable which will use what you have in place inside the function. Passing the connection to the function is the *preferred* method of making a connection available in a function. The `global` keyword should be avoided.

Now, call the function with your established connection variable:

```
echo getAddress($conn);
```

`$conn` here is the successful connection from your included file. This will put the connection into the scope of your function and your query should be successful if all else is equal.

Answer (score 0):

try doing

```
function getAddress()
{
  global $conn;
  // rest of code
}
```

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yes! i agree. i think passing the `$conn` variable as a function parameter would be the best way to go about it